# Delphi command line compiler - using same library path as the IDE

Tags: delphi, dcc32

Is there a way to instruct DCC32 to use the same library path that is used by the IDE (i.e. in Tools/Options/Environment Options/Delphi Options/Library - Win32)?

For obvious reasons, I do *not* want to maintain two lists of directories (one in a cfg file, one in the Delphi IDE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Delphi 2006 or later, you can use MSBuild instead of dcc32, and MSBuild will use the same search path as the IDE

Comment: No, it will not use. Under Hudson+MSBuild unit search path from IDE settings not used.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a cfg file in your project directory called yourprojectnamedpr.cfg which actually should contain all the directories defined in the IDE for that project.

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid;  I don't want to maintain more than one list of directories.  If I change my search path, I don't want to go change the cfg file for every project as well.

Comment: But only the project directories. Not the IDE environment options, in particular not the 'lib' path.

Answer (score 1):

It is a **lot** of work to use DCC32 to build from the command line.  MSBuild is far easier.  The library path is stored in the registry, but the location depends on the Delphi version, for example (python code):

```
if BDSVER == '5.0':
    CompanyText = 'Borland'
else:
    CompanyText = 'CodeGear'

key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,'Software\\' + CompanyText + '\\BDS\\' + BDSVER + '\\Library')    
IncludePath = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key,'Search Path')[0]

# Then you must replace the environment vars $(BDS), $(BDSCOMMONDOR) etc
IncludePath = ReplaceEnvironVars(IncludePath)
```

And there is much more to do.  You must also obtain the search path, and you must obtain conditional defines from the .dproj file, etc.

I wrote a complete automated build tool in python (for BDSVER >= 5), back when Delphi 2007 installed on XP x64 had a broken MSBuild.  Later, it turned out that some [required configuration files](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=54409)  were not copied into the correct .NET folder by the Delphi installer.  Copying these files to the correct location fixed the problem, and now I use MSBuild.

Comment: Library and browsing path is also in C:\Documents and Settings\<User Name>\Application Data\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\EnvOptions.proj (on XP) or C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\EnvOptions.proj if you're on Vista or Windows 7 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821112/how-does-msbuild-find-the-delphi-search-path

Comment: @mjustin, yes, that's right, it is even more work to handle those cases.   It is better just to use MSBuild.

Comment: Never really used MSBuild from the command line - Apache Ant and a build.xml file makes me happy, YMMV :)

Comment: C:\source> msbuild MyAppName.dproj is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an older Delphi (e.g. Delphi 7), you must put all your information in the "Search Path" Directory option in your IDE. It will be saved in your .dof file. **The .dof file is the main reference of your project.**

The IDE will also automatically update the .cfg every time you change the project configuration. The .cfg is the specifies the compilation option for the command line compiler. Both the .cfg and the .dof must be under version control.

If, instead of editing your .dof file from the IDE,  you manually edit it, you can use the [dof2cfg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dof2cfg/) utility to generate a new .cfg from your .dof. You will have to put it in your build chain.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild project.dproj
```